# Using triggers to update db-cache

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

In a legacy system, I'm trying to attach triggers to all three events of a table. The table contains values that aggregate up to an ... aggregate ... :)

For some users, creating this aggregate takes a while, because it's done several times on several groups of rows.

So what I'm trying to do is create a trigger on the table, that triggers on INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE and "caches" the aggregate to another table. So the web-interface showing the aggregates can just read from this table.

The INSERT and UPDATE triggers work just fine and inserts the values correctly. However, the DELETE trigger looks like it's not firing. The counts are never updated on delete. This lead me to think that the row deletion is not done until *after* the trigger has run. So the trigger actually runs, but it doesn't notice that a row is deleted...

Or do I need to look somewhere else? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you use an indexed view instead.

- [Improving Performance with SQL Server 2008 Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- [Creating Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx)
- [Designing Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864.aspx)

Indexed views are suited for situations where you need fast aggregates.

> For a standard view, the overhead of dynamically building the result
>   set for each query that references a view can be significant for views
>   that involve complex processing of large numbers of rows, such as
>   aggregating lots of data, or joining many rows. If such views are
>   frequently referenced in queries, you can improve performance by
>   creating a unique clustered index on the view. When a unique clustered
>   index is created on a view, the result set is stored in the database
>   just like a table with a clustered index is stored.